# Strange PHP response

Tags: php

I have 2 different server machine, with the same code it generate responses :

1. `"role_options": [
     {
       "usrl_id": 25,
       "usrl_enabled": "DISABLE",
       "usrl_level": "STAFF",
       "csms_id": 2,
       "csms_name": "EAST MALL - GRAND INDONESIA",
       "rlms_id": 20,
       "rlms_name": "Administrative",
       "drms_id": 2,
       "drms_name": "South Lobby"
     },`
2. `"role_options": [
     {
       "usrl_id": "25",
       "usrl_enabled": "DISABLE",
       "usrl_level": "STAFF",
       "csms_id": "2",
       "csms_name": "EAST MALL - GRAND INDONESIA",
       "rlms_id": "20",
       "rlms_name": "Administrative",
       "drms_id": "2",
       "drms_name": "South Lobby"
     },`

I use laravel 5.x, if u see that the first server is auto casting to integer, and the others still casting to string. ( `usrl_id` )

How can i make it works auto casting to integer ?
the first server is ngingX & localhost using php 7.0 mySQL

the second server is Apache using php 7.0 Maria DB

Comment: check your database field definitions

Comment: ahh.. Maria DB , where is the settings ?